# Making all occurrences of a specific word capital?

Tags: php

I've got a few recurring words on my website that appear quite frequently. Is there any way to make all occurrences of that specific word all capitals?

Comment: If you're in linux, use `sed -i 's/yourword/Your Word/g'` recursively.

Comment: Please expand on your question. Are you reading from a database? Are you using a CMS? How do you handle your output? There are ways to search for an occurrence of a string but we need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, it's being ready from a MySQL database. I simply want to take every occurence of a specific word and capitalize the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). It's the case-insensitive version of [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Once you have the content from the database inside of a variable you can do the following before you output it:

```
$content = str_ireplace('replace', 'REPLACE', $content);
```

This is searching for the case-insensitive text `replace` inside of `$content` and changing all occurrences to `REPLACE`. This will not only change whole words, it will change partials as well, for example it will change `replaced` to `REPLACEd`.

If you would like to only select whole words you will need to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) with the [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function. Example:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(\W|^)replace(\W|$)/i', '${1}REPLACE${2}', $content);
```

This matches all case-insensitive occurrences of the word `replace` that are either next to a non-word character (`/W`) or the beginning (`^`) or end (`$`) of a line, and replaces it with `REPLACE` plus whatever was before it (`${1}`) and after it (`${2}`).